# Which Hebrew word does Jesus use for "hell"?

Tags: jesus, luke

Luke 16:23

> And in hell he lift up his eyes, being in torments, and seeth Abraham afar off, and Lazarus in his bosom.

When Jesus speaks this to the live audience, which Hebrew word does Jesus use for "hell"?

Comment: Welcome to Bible Hermeneutics SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For answer specific to Luke 16:23 go to 2).**

**1)** Matt. 5:22,29,30 has a Hebrew/Aramaic word transliterated into Greek γέενναν (Gehenna) גֵּיהִנּוֹם
.  Gehenna occurs 11 times in the Gospels (Matt. 5:22,39,30; 10:28; 18:9; 23:15,33; Mark 9:43,45,47; Luke 12:5), but only once outside the Gospels in James 3:6.

> Gehenna is the Valley of Hinnom where the fire burned continually. Here idolatrous Jews once offered their children to Molech (2 Kings 23:10). Jesus finds one cause of murder to be abusive language. Gehenna “should be carefully distinguished from Hades (ᾁδης [hāidēs]) which is never used for the place of punishment, but for the place of departed spirits, without reference to their moral condition” (Vincent). The place of torment is in Hades (Luke 16:23), but so is heaven.
> --
> Robertson, A. T. (1933). Word Pictures in the New Testament (Matt 5:22). Nashville, TN: Broadman Press.

> “The hell of fire” is literally “the Gehenna of fire,” which refers to the standard Jewish concept of Gehinnom, the opposite of paradise; in Gehinnom the wicked would be burned up (according to some Jewish teachers) or eternally tortured (according to other Jewish teachers). Not only the outward act of murder but also the inward choice of anger that generates such acts violates the spirit of God’s law against murder.
> --
> Keener, C. S. (1993). The IVP Bible background commentary: New Testament (Mt 5:21–22). Downers Grove, IL: InterVarsity Press.

**2)** **Luke 16:23** has the Greek word ᾅδης, translated *hell*.  Hades is the abode of the dead in Greek.  It is very likely that this translated Jesus using the word Sheol, שְׁאוֹל. Hades is only used four times in the gospels. Twice in Matt. (11:23; 16:18), and twice in Luke (10:15; **16:23**).

> The rich man also died and was buried, 23 and in Hades [ἐν τῷ ᾅδῃ], being in torment, he lifted up his eyes and saw Abraham far off and Lazarus at his side. 24 And he called out, ‘Father Abraham, have mercy on me, and send Lazarus to dip the end of his finger in water and cool my tongue, for I am in anguish in this flame.
> (Luke 16:22–24, ESV)

Hebrew words the Septuagint (LXX) translates (from Logos Bible Software):

[image]

**3)** In Matt. 25:41 Jesus referred to hell as "eternal fire" (τὸ πῦρ τὸ αἰώνιον, אֵשׁ עוֹלָם) and 25:46 "eternal punishment" (κόλασιν αἰώνιον, עֹנֶשׁ עוֹלָם).

> “Then he will say to those on his left, ‘Depart from me, you cursed, into the **eternal fire** prepared for the devil and his angels.... And these will go away into **eternal punishment**, but the righteous into eternal life.”
> (Matt. 25:41,46, ESV)

Eternal fire = hell

> And if your hand or your foot causes you to sin, cut it off and throw it away. It is better for you to enter life crippled or lame than with two hands or two feet to be thrown into **the eternal fire**. 9 And if your eye causes you to sin, tear it out and throw it away. It is better for you to enter life with one eye than with two eyes to be thrown into **the hell of fire**.
> (Matt. 18:8–9, ESV)

Hell = unquenchable fire

> And if your hand causes you to sin, cut it off. It is better for you to enter life crippled than with two hands to go **to hell, to the unquenchable fire.** 45 And if your foot causes you to sin, cut it off. It is better for you to enter life lame than with two feet to be thrown into hell. 47 And if your eye causes you to sin, tear it out. It is better for you to enter the kingdom of God with one eye than with two eyes to be thrown into hell, 48 ‘where their **worm does not die and the fire is not quenched**.’
> (Mark 9:43–48, ESV)

Comment: Excellent +1. It would be improved if you provided refereces to the traditional teachings you reference (being burnt up or eternally punished)

Comment: @Robert The references for the quotes are at the end of the quotes.  For other references see edit.

Comment: Also edit added 3)

Answer (score 1):

Most modern versions translate Luke 16:23 something like the BSB:

> In Hades, where he was in torment, he looked up and saw Abraham from
> afar, with Lazarus by his side.

The **Greek** word translated "hell" in the KJV is the Greek word, hades, ᾍδης.  [Note that the NT is written in Greek not Hebrew.] Let us observe several things about this:

- In most cases, the word translated "hell" in the KJV is γέεννα = "gehenna" which BDAG suggests is:

> Greekized (Josh 15:8, 18:16, 2 Chron 28:3, Jer 7:32, cp 2 Kings 23:10)
> ... Valley of the sons of Hinnom, a ravine south Jerusalem.  There
> according to later Jewish popular belief, God's final judgement was to
> take place.  In the Gospels it is the place of punishment in the next
> life ...

In most places, ᾍδης (hades) is either transliterated by modern versions to avoid the controversy surrounding its translation.  With the exception of Luke 16:23, the word occurs 10 times, Matt 11:23; 16:18; Luke 10:15; 16:23; Acts 2:27, 31; Rev 1:18; 6:8; 20:13, 14.  In none of these places is eternal punishment mentioned or implied.  Hades is simply the Greek word for grave or crypt being the place of the dead.  Here is a good example:

> Acts 2:25-27, 31 - David says about Him: ‘I saw the Lord always before
> me; because He is at my right hand, I will not be shaken. Therefore my
> heart is glad and my tongue rejoices; my body also will dwell in hope,
> because You will not abandon my soul to **Hades** nor will You let
> Your Holy One see decay. ... Foreseeing this, David spoke about the
> resurrection of the Christ, that He was not abandoned to **Hades**,
> nor did His body see decay.

The parable that Jesus tells in Luke 16:19-31, and its interpretation, is controversial and might be the subject of another question.  However, we should note that whatever interpretation is adopted, there are clear references to Greek mythology as in several other places such as Rev 1:9-17 (hecetar) and Rev 12 (the dragon) and Rev 13 (chimeras).